# Getting undefined result from Next 13.4.3

Tags: reactjs, next.js, graphql

I am following a tutorial online that uses the older version of Next. I am now using Next 13, and tried to implement getStaticProp() to fetch data from my api, but cannot use that function under the pages folder. I've tried using the getData() to fetch as well. What I don't really understand is that it works fine on the index.tsx page, and I moved it into Home.tsx to import and it breaks and I keep getting undefined result in my terminal.

- I've tried using the getData() to fetch as well. What I don't really understand is that it works fine on the index.tsx page, and I moved it into Home.tsx to import and it breaks and I keep getting undefined result in my terminal.
- I've tried checking for course details before returning it

My code:

```
import { gql, GraphQLClient } from "graphql-request";
import CourseSection from '../components/CourseSection'

export default function index({course}) {
  console.log(course)
  return (
    <div className="">
      {course.courseDetails.map(section => <CourseSection details =
      {section} key={section.id}/>)}
    </div>
  );
}

 

const query = gql`
  query {
    course {
      id
      name
      slug
      courseDetails {
        ... on NavbarRecord {
          __typename
          logoText
          home
          about
          login
        }
        ... on AboutSectionRecord {
          __typename
          bigTitle
          tutor {
            url
            height
            width
          }
          description
          buttonText
        }
        ... on CourseHeaderRecord {
          __typename
          bigTitle
          smallTitle
          description
          buttonText
        }
        ... on CalloutRecord {
          __typename
          bigTitle
          smallTitle
          description
          image {
            url
            height
            width
          }
        }
        ... on LearnSectionRecord {
          __typename
          hoursOfContent
          hoursOfContentText
          numberOfLessons
          numberOfLessonsText
          title
          id
          learningPoint {
            title
            id
          }
        }
        ... on PricingSectionRecord {
          __typename
          title
          id
          pricingCard {
            isFree
            priceInCents
            priceSuffix
            title
            id
            description
            finePrint
            featured
            buttonText
          }
        }
        ... on FooterRecord {
          __typename
          terms
          privacy
          support
          copyright
        }
      }
    }
  }
`;

export async function getStaticProps() {
  const endpoint = "https://graphql.datocms.com";
  const graphQLClient = new GraphQLClient(endpoint, {
    headers: {
      "content-type": "application/json",
      authorization: "Bearer " + process.env.DATOCMS_API_KEY,
    },
  });
  const course = await graphQLClient.request(query);
  console.log(course);
  return {
    props: course,
  };
}
```

The import:

```
import React from 'react'
import Home from './Home'

function index() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Home/>
    </div>
  )
}

export default index
```